# LibraryLink Documentation

Tags: bugs, documentation, librarylink

**Bug fixed in version 10.0.0**

---

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html) for LibraryLink has the following example

```c
DLLEXPORT int demo_TI_R(WolframLibraryData libData,
 mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
 MTensor T0;
 mint I0;
 double R0;
 T0 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
 I0 = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
 R0 = libData->MTensorVector_getReal(T0, I0);
 MArgument_setReal(Res, R0);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what the command `MTensorVector_getReal` does. This looks like it is undocumented.

Similarly, in the following [example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html) from the documentation, it is not clear what `funStruct` is, and where it is coming from. Should it be `libData` instead?

```c
DLLEXPORT int demo1_TI_R(WolframLibraryData libData,
 mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
 MTensor T0;
 mint I0;
 double R0;
 T0 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
 I0 = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
 R0 = funStruct->MTensorVector_getReal( T0, I0);
 libData->MTensor_free(T0);
MArgument_setReal(Res, R0);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide links to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Mathematica.html) where these are found?

Comment: @rcollyer it's here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html

Comment: @xslittlegrass why don't you edit that in, and get the 2 points for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My advice is to not rely on the code samples in the documentation. It has proven to be unreliable. For instance

- In the documentation to [`MTensor_getComplexData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/ref/callbacks/MTensor_getComplexData.html) the example doesn't even use the function.
- The documentation to [`MTensor_free`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/ref/callbacks/MTensor_free.html) can barely be called documentation since it does not explain about memory allocation etc
- The documentation to [`AbortQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/ref/callbacks/AbortQ.html) states that this function returns a mystical `TRUE` value, where the definitions in `"WolframLibrary.h"` clearly shows that it is `#define True 1`

These things and the undocumented function you found are only some of the small mistakes/typos you find around the *WolframLibrary* documentation.

### Regarding your two questions

I can only guess to answer your questions. I believe

```
double MTensorVector_getReal(MTensor t, mint pos)
```

is equivalent to

```
int MTensor_getReal(MTensor t, mint *pos, mreal *res)
```

with the difference that it is specifically made for rank 1 tensors. The advantage is that you can simply pass an integer as position and not a pointer and you get the result directly back from the function. The only reference I found in all `*.m` or `*.c` files is in `CodeGenerator.m` located in

```
FileNames["CodeGenerator.m", {$InstallationDirectory}, 4]
(* 
 {"/Applications/Development/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/GPUTools/CodeGenerator.m"}
*)
```

So this function was probably planned to make it to the final WolframLink API but didn't in the end.

**I couldn't find this function in neither the header files or the `libWolframRTL` so it seems you cannot use it in version 9.0.1!**

Regarding the `funStruct` in your second example, there is a similar thing in compiled functions which are converted to C code. A simple example is the following

```
<< CCodeGenerator`;
CCodeStringGenerate[Compile[{}, 1], "fun"]
```

When you examine the created code you see that it has a `static` variable `funStructCompile` which is used in an equivalent way as in your example. I assume the `funStruct` in your example is a typo.

### Further reading

As I said in the beginning, although the documentation (especially the [WolframLibrary tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/Overview.html)) gives insight into the usage, I would not count on that code blocks are up to date.

I would recommend that you look into the example files you find here

```
FileNames["demo*.c", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]
```

There you find the correct versions of the functions `demo_TI_R` and `demo1_TI_R` in `"demo.c"`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not sure whether double MTensorVector_getReal(MTensor t, mint pos) really exists. Will wait a bit before accepting.

Comment: @asim have you tried running it? If there are no errors, than it exists, otherwise ...

Comment: @halirutan, I filed the 3 issues as bugs against the documentation. Should there be more, just send them to suuport@wolfram.com. Thanks.

Comment: @asim It seems `MTensorVector_getReal` doesn't exist in neither the header files nor the library itself. I'll check older versions of Mathematica when I have time. There must be some more references anywhere.

Comment: @halirutan I am trying to learn library link these days. Just as you said, the official documentation sucks, and also my IQ. I just got errors and errors, when I write on my own. Do you have good resources which can make the learning not such painful? :）